# Populate dropdown menu from MySQL database?

Tags: php, database

I have read a few threads but can not figure out the solution to my problem. 
I want to display the names of different events in my table 'events' in a dropdown menu.

The code I have is:

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('test');

$sql = "SELECT 'event name' FROM events";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='event name'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['event name'] ."'>" . $row['event name'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

?>
```

I am getting a drop down menu that displays 'event name' 3 times. I have 3 entries in the event name table however it is not displaying their names?

Comment: Code look ok, If you have no data in table or something misspell like table name or field name.

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj If he mis spells, an error will be thrown for unknown column name or PHP error for wrong query

Comment: What you see in HTML source?

Comment: Just realized there is a space in 'event name' when I double checked in phpmyadmin. However in the dropdown menu it is now just displaying 'event name' 3 times (there are 3 different event names however it is not displaying the correct names)

Comment: @Mr. Allen, There are lot of instances when error are off through php.ini or in application. And even developer did not on the errors on development time.

Answer (score 0):

Now after nathan's change, error should be seen easily space between field name and also apostrophe on around field. Just need to remove apostrophe  and space between fieldname.

Comment: Sorry, not to sure where you are talking about? It is displaying 3 options but they are all 'event name'

Comment: You need to replace apostrophe ( around field-name in query) with backtick or just remove apostophe. Apostrophe convert fieldname as constant string instead of actual field in select query. So you are getting `event name` thrice instead of data.